# Stop for loop iteration trough a list at a certain point

Tags: python

Basically I want that my for loop stops itself after a certain element in the list is being processed. Here is the code:

```
vids = [
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=626de171d928a',
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6050c75748399',
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6277dbe97910c',
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=5d660515990ec&pkey=150469821',
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6201e028e3811',
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6201e028e3811',
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=60dd6838ce483',
]

for v in vids:
    try:
        vids.remove(v)
        if '&pkey=' in v:
            raise StopIteration
    except StopIteration:
        break

print(vids)
```

The output is:

```
[
        'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=626de171d928a',
        'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6050c75748399',
        'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6277dbe97910c',
        'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=5d660515990ec&pkey=150469821',
        'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6201e028e3811',
        'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6201e028e3811',
        'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=60dd6838ce483',
    ]
```

As you can see nothing changes, but i don't know where my code is faulty. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: the code works for me (it modifies the list) but you should change it to ```for v in list(vids):``` to get the behaviour I think you expect

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to modify the list you are iterating over.

Comment: If you are going to stop the iteration you must use a while loop, your code doesn't follow pip8 guidelines and it's not readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to go about this would probably be to create a new list which is basically a copy of the previous one from the wanted item onwards. There are many ways to do that but, probably the *cutest* one is the following:

```
new_list = vids[next((i for i, v in enumerate(vids) if '&pkey=' in v), len(vids)):]
```

What you are basically doing is:

1. finding the first element that satisfies your condition by
   `next((i for i, v in enumerate(vids) if '&pkey=' in v)` and then
2. slicing the list from that element onwards.

Note that if the string you are searching for does not exist, the `new_list` comes out empty (`[]`).

Also note, that the code as given above, also returns the element you are searching for (inclusive). If you want to make it exclusive, just add one (`next((i+1..`). The rest stays the same.

Comment: this keeps the item that contains ```'&pkey='``` whereas I believe OP also wants this removed

Comment: @Nin17 if OP does not want that element, they have to also specify what happens if it is the last one in the original list. The code is easy to adjust whatever the desired behaviour may be.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution uses another list and a `for` loop:

```
vids = [
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=626de171d928a',
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6050c75748399',
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6277dbe97910c',
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=5d660515990ec&pkey=150469821',
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6201e028e3811',
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6201e028e3811',
    'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=60dd6838ce483',
]
new_vids = []
seen = False

for vid in vids:
    if '&pkey=' in vid:
        seen = True
    if seen:
        new_vids.append(vid)
print(new_vids)
# ['https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=5d660515990ec&pkey=150469821', 'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6201e028e3811', 'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=6201e028e3811', 'https://www.itatv.com/ita_video.php?viewkey=60dd6838ce483']
```

Note that it is usually a bad idea to modify the list while iterating over it. Hence, a new list is used. While not the most efficient, this solution is easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: why `new_vids += [vid]` and not just `new_vids.append(vid)`